# Converting an array to a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have an array `A`. I want to identify all locations with element 1 and convert it to a list as shown in the expected output. But I am getting an error.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

B=np.where(A==1)

B=B.tolist()
print(B)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    B=B.tolist()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

The expected output is

```
[1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `B` before you call `tolist`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please think carefully about the logic. "I want to identify all locations with element 1 and convert it to a list as shown in the expected output." - **what** do you want to "convert"? It is not the original array `A`, but **the locations** that you got back from the `.where` call - right? So. **Is that result an array**? What is it instead?

Comment: Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to *examine* problems before asking. For example, if you get an error message from code like `B=B.tolist()`, then it should be clear that there is a problem with trying to use `.tolist` on `B` - therefore, the next step in reasoning about the problem, should be to **check what `B` is**. When you do this, you will find that you have an ordinary Python `tuple`, not a Numpy array. Then you can see what is in that tuple: **one** element, which is the array that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) used with only the condition returns a tuple of arrays containing indices; one array for each dimension of the array. According to the docs, this is much like [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), which is the recommended approach over `np.where`. So, since your array is one dimensional, `np.where` will return a tuple with one element, inside of which is the array containing the indices in your expected output. You can resolve your problem by accessing into the tuple like `np.where(A == 1)[0].tolist()`.

However, I recommend using [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html#numpy.flatnonzero) instead, which avoids the hassle entirely:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

B = np.flatnonzero(A).tolist()
```

B:

```
[1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 11]
```

PS: when all other elements are 0, you don't have to explicitly compare to 1 ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

indices = np.where(A == 1)[0]
B = indices.tolist()

print(B)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should access the first element of this tuple with `B[0]` :

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

B=np.where(A==1)

B = B[0].tolist()
print(B) # [1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 11]
```